# Change image resolution in html

Tags: html

```
 <style>
 #text{
 background-image:url('/../image.jpg');
 <<image-resolution:???>>
 }
 </style>
```

I have a `CSS` where I use an image as the background. `[width = 5000p, height = 3000px, horizontal and vertical resolution = 72dpi]`
The image appears with a very big size and the pic does not cover the screen completely. Is there a way I can change the size/resolution of the image using `image-resolution` or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`background-size` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) to change the size of your image.

```
 #text{
     background-image:url('/../image.jpg');
     background-size: 100px 100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all image-resolution tag belongs to css3 and all the browsers might not support this but if you want to do this then try to provide image resolution like this :

```
<style>
image-resolution: 72dpi; 
</style>
```

All the best....

Answer (score 0):

Tiffon gave you the correct answer. But in the "real world" you'll never use such a big image for a repeated background.

Typical sizes are, for example:

- 200px X 200px (repeat)
- 10px X 1000px (repeat-x)
- 2000px X 10px (repeat-y)

Of course, you have also to consider the weight of the images: 40/50Kb could be an approsimative max size.

In conclusion, instead of use the css rule, I suggest to you to resize and compress (JPG compression, from 50% to 80%) the image. You can do that with software like Paint or [FastStone Resizer](http://www.faststone.org/FSResizerDetail.htm), a very useful freeware.